# Select from table which not in another table with condition

Tags: mysql

got two tables
node:

```
nid INT(10)
type (VARCHAR(32))

node_hit_count

nid INT(10)
totalcount (bigint(20))
```

i need to select all `nid`s from `node` table which are not in `node_hit_count` table and `WHERE` `node` type is equal to `feature` or `home` or `competition`

What i have tried, its wrong, and my mind is gonna blow :/

```
select * from node left join node_hit_counter on node.nid=node_hit_counter.nid 

where hit.nid is null and node.type IN ('feature', 'home', 'competition')
```

Comment: i think your alias "hit" do not exists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the `hit.nid` in the `WHERE` clause. You have to use `WHERE node.nid IS NULL` instead like so:

```
select node.*
from node 
left join node_hit_counter on node.nid = node_hit_counter.nid 
where node.nid is null 
  and node.type IN ('feature', 'home', 'competition');
```

**OR:**

```
SELECT *
FROM node
WHERE nid NOT IN(SELECT nid FROM node_hit_counter WHERE nid IS NOT NULL)
  AND type IN ('feature', 'home', 'competition');
```

Answer (score 1):

try this and you can use your hit.nid in where clause :o)

```
select n.* 
from node n
left join node_hit_counter hit on n.nid=hit.nid 
where hit.nid is null 
and n.type IN ('feature', 'home', 'competition')
```